# How do I fill out IRS form 1310, as a successor trustee? Reissue a check from the IRS?

Tags: united-states, irs, trusts

I am the successor trustee for an individual who had a living trust.  Thus there was no court, no probate.  A refund was due the individual, but the IRS chose to issue a check rather than direct deposit.

My goal: get the check reissued in the name of the trust.
But form 1310 is confusing me.  My answers on this form are:

1  Did the decedent leave a will?  **yes**
2a Has a court appointed a representative?  **no**
2b If you answered no, will one be appointed?  **no**
3  As the person claiming the refund, will you follow the state law?  **yes**

But do I enter my name or the name of the trust in the various boxes?
Do I enter my SSN or the Trust's EIN?
How do I get them to issue a new check in the name of the trust?

IRS instructions are at https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1310

Comment: Can you include the state of the decedent, are you the executor named in the will, and what if any assets existed outside of the trust?

Comment: California.  The will was a pour over into the trust.  No significant assets exist outside of trust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update August 2019: after multiple rounds of wrong information I had to file form 1310.  The check came in my personal name.  I had to cash that check as myself, then make a matching deposit to the Trust.

Original response:
I called the IRS, reached the trust division, and was told that this is just one situation where no form applies.  I was instructed to write a letter requesting the re-issue, and include proof of the name of the successor trust.  I was told not to use form 1310.

Please note my bank's policy prohibits depositing checks made to the name of the decedent.  A dozen or more times now I've had to get a check reissued to the name of the trust, a process that generally goes fairly smoothly.